# Can multiple Blue Prism runtime resources be installed in a single VM?

Tags: blueprism

My client doesn't want to commission one VM per runtime resource. Hence, I am trying to get multiple resources to work in one single VM (without any luck). Has anyone set this up before?

Comment: Did you search google? You should add what you have already tried.

Comment: @Abrar Nomrally, a Google search would help and would be advisable for the OP. However, the Blue Prism platform materials are normally not searchable in this manner as they're mostly "Commercial in Confidence".

Answer (score 1):

The Blue Prism Infrastructure Reference Guide (major version 6; document version 1.0) deals directly with this question in section 5.9, and outlines the challenges with the approach. Since the contents of the document are covered under an NDA, you'll have to acquire it from your client's account manager.

At a basic level, it boils down to ensuring that (a) the Runtime Resource communication and callback ports don't collide, and (b) your Business Objects can handle having multiple instances of an application open and being able to pick out the single instance they need to interact with when attaching. The latter point is a bit more difficult than it sounds to accomplish successfully and at scale, and near impossible if attempting to use Region mode ("surface automation") to accomplish an automation.

Comment: The Infrastructure Reference Guide states that multiple Runtime Resources can be configured by specifying different listening ports. This can be done but with the integration with Login Agent, can the Login Agent be configured to listen on multiple ports? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need multiple Login Agents as there is always only one physical/virtual screen pre computer.

Answer (score 0):

Although multiple runtime resources can run in parallel (via using different ports) and interact with multiple applications in the same time, there is a risk that they will collide while attaching to application or interacting with it. It is also very complicated or impossible if some of your processes uses surface automation (= automation via recognizing objects on screen as images).